# Send Updates to Users using Facebook CheckBox plugin

Tags: javascript, java, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I'm new to Facebook's Messenger platform so I hsve a conceptual doubt. I'm trying to implement a feature using Messenger checkbox plugin(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/checkbox-plugin) where If a user in my website checks the plugin while searching for an item in my website then He will recieve updates for that item on facebook messenger from my website.

Will Messenger bot be used to implement this functionality. I know that the bot's API are in Python, node.js & Ruby. I'm trying to implement this feature using plin javascript and java at the backend.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what do you try until now? what problems you're facing?

Comment: I have to implement this feature..just wanted to know whether this is possible or not as I found the documentation confusing

Comment: It's possible. You may use the JavaScript SDK as suggested in the docs and, once the user allow your site to sent message to him by clicking the checkbox, you'll receive a `user_ref` information from the API. You need this information (and the `access_token`) to send the message (you can see the endpoint to send message in the docs as well). You should be familiar with FB Auth, Permission and API flows to achieve this. Take your time reading some tutorials about these topics before trying to achieve what you want. ;-)

Comment: Can you please list the urls where all this is mentioned...in the checkbox plugin page(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/checkbox-plugin) it'a mentioned that we have to provide the "user_ref" in the html code....Hence getting confused looking at the docs.

Comment: Implementation section, 2nd paragraph "The web plugin takes a `user_ref` parameter which is used as an identifier for the user. When the user finishes the flow, we will pass this identifier back to you to identify the user." Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153714/facebook-messenger-checkbox-plugin-is-hidden) as well, the guys there has some code that you can use. As I said, if you're not familiar with how the SDK/API works...it will be really hard to achieve what you want.

Comment: Sending updates to users requires the use of the page access token - so that part must be done server-side. But before you start implementing, I recommend that you thoroughly check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview to see if the kind of information you want to send fits into one of the three defined use cases for subscription messaging. I see a lot of people complaining that Facebook rejected their bot in review - because they tried to send stuff that _doesn’t_ fit those use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your updates.

Comment: HI @Lucy, Did you setup to send updates to user? I am trying it, But I have some doubt to do it,