# Facebook messenger checkbox plugin is hidden (already checked other answers)

Tags: facebook, checkbox

I have the same problem like asked here: [Facebook messenger checkbox plugin is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153714/facebook-messenger-checkbox-plugin-is-hidden)

I tried the implementation of the Facebook Checkbox Plugin according to Facebooks documentation but it won't show on my VM in my Company.

The Facebook SDK Implementation works fine, I tried the "Share" and "Like"-Button, which show up correct.

I have a Facbook Page which has public access and a Messenger APP in DEV-mode. The "Send-API" from Facebook works correct too: I am able to send message to myself as administrator from my Webpage on my development VM.

Following Steps are done: use a random `user_ref` on every request, set my page on the whitelist, use "https", visit my page FB-loggedIN and FB-loggedOut

But the result ends in Markup and Log-Infos like this screen:
[See FF DeveloperTools Markup Screenshot for current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3azw.jpg)

According to this I visited a page given as `origin` where the Plugin should work (see first link in my question) - but there the plugins' HTML is the same like mine.

So is there a general problem on Facebooks' site or is there quite more necessary, to get this plugin running? Could it be a problem with self-signed certificate on my VM?

At the moment I don't want to notify or login any user. All I want is that the checkbox is shown.

Pherhaps anyone has an idea or the same experiences :)

Additional Info: the console shows following message
`fb:messenger_checkbox failed to resize in 45s`

Answer (score 5):

after some fiddling we found out that a registered webhook is required (even if you dont consume the events) to make the messenger checkbox plugin render properly.

Comment: hi, im having the same issue. what webhook is required for this to work?

Comment: Here's more details on setting up the webhook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook