# Facebook Messenger Checkbox Plugin not working / rendering

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We've created a new Facebook App (not reviewed) and added the Messenger Product. We've connected our Facebook Page (Visible: Public) with our App and added a Webhook to the App. As described in the documentation we also have whitelisted our domain in the page settings. But still the plugin does not get rendered. Console output: 'Plugin was hidden'

When testing we're logged in as a Facebook user which has an admin role in the app as well as on the page.

Below you can see how we've integrated the messenger checkbox plugin. As origin we use our domain where the plugin is integrated.

```js
<script>
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '766805437589568',
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v9.0'
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('messenger_checkbox', function(e) {
            console.log("messenger_checkbox event");
            console.log(e);

            if (e.event == 'rendered') {
                console.log("Plugin was rendered");
            } else if (e.event == 'checkbox') {
                var checkboxState = e.state;
                console.log("Checkbox state: " + checkboxState);
            } else if (e.event == 'not_you') {
                console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
            } else if (e.event == 'hidden') {
                console.log("Plugin was hidden");
            }

        });
    };
</script>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

```html
<div class="fb-messenger-checkbox" 
  origin='https://example.com'
  page_id=100378165398818
  messenger_app_id=766805437589568
  user_ref="%%uniqueIdForEveryRender%%" 
  allow_login="false" 
  size="large" 
  skin="dark" 
  center_align="true">
</div>
```

In the printscreen you can see the output from the dev console.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv5pW.png)

We've already checked the following post [Facebook messenger checkbox plugin is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153714/facebook-messenger-checkbox-plugin-is-hidden).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin#troubleshooting says, _“1. Verify that your bot is actually approved for the pages_messaging permission.”_ - so that doesn’t sound to me as if this was actually supposed to work with a not yet reviewed app …?

Comment: @CBroe I have submitted our app for review and am currently waiting for feedback. However, I find it a bit strange that an app has to be submitted for review before it has been developed. I don't understand this approach from Facebook.

Comment: It would make little sense to show the plugin to normal users, before your app is reviewed and functional. But with the `allow_login` parameter set to true, at the point when the plugin is supposed to render, it could be yet unknown, whether the user viewing your page actually has any role in your app, or is just a normal user. So instead of adding more complexity here, they probably have decided to make this particular aspect (that plugin is probably a rather small part of your overall app functionality) only available to already reviewed apps, that’d make sense to me.

Comment: Yes could be. Let you know as soon as I have feedback from the review team.

Comment: We now have "Advanced access" for `pages_messaging` but it is still not working. Running out of ideas. Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: Did you go through all the troubleshooting tips yet? Is your app in live or dev mode now?

Comment: Yes we've checked all the troubleshooting tips from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin/). Facebook works new with data access levels. Therefore we have standard access everywhere and for `pages_messaging, public_profile, email` Advanced Access.

Comment: The Chat Plugin has an additional requirement mentioned, regarding the Referrer send by the parent page - maybe the same applies for the Checkbox plugin, but they forgot to mention it? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin#debug-tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a GDPR related issue:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/europe-updates#nov-30th-2020

In the table **Affected features and APIs with mitigations** there is an entry for the checkbox plugin:

[image]

So we have no choice but to wait until facebook switches the service back on.